# big-endian BinaryReader gives wrong value when reading long

Tags: c#, memorystream, endianness

I am currently working on a socket server.
The client sends data in BigEdian format so I
Decided to use [this](https://github.com/jamesqo/Be.IO) package. But for Int64 it gives me a different value

This is the test code. It works fine for int32

```
long val = ((long)868324021119164);
byte[] longval = BitConverter.GetBytes((long)868324021119164);
Array.Reverse(longval);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(longval))
using (BeBinaryReader BeReader = new BeBinaryReader(stream))
{
   Console.WriteLine(BeReader.ReadInt64());
}
```

This was my result 8130168015229752764

I looked into the [source code](https://github.com/jamesqo/Be.IO)
And found these Functions.
I don't have any experience with unsafe code. So I don't know if they are wrong

```
public override long ReadInt64()
{
    FillBuffer(8);
    fixed (byte* p = buffer)
         return BigEndian.ReadInt64(p);
}


[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static long ReadInt64(byte* p)
{
    int lo = ReadInt32(p);
    int hi = ReadInt32(p + 4);
    return (long)hi << 32 | (uint)lo;
}
```

I have a windows 10 64 bits Pc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code here:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static long ReadInt64(byte* p)
{
    int lo = ReadInt32(p);
    int hi = ReadInt32(p + 4);
    return (long)hi << 32 | (uint)lo;
}
```

Doesn't seem right. It should have been:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static long ReadInt64(byte* p)
{
    int hi = ReadInt32(p);
    int lo = ReadInt32(p + 4);
    return (long)hi << 32 | (uint)lo;
}
```

In big endian, the high 32-bit number comes first. The code inverts that. You should submit a bug report, and maybe suggest the author to write some unit tests :)

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I found out the bug was already submitted. But not changed in the package